# Set document value with REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to fill a document field via the Docusign Esignature REST API and having some trouble. I created an envelope from a template which has a PO # field:

[image]

I can see this field by making a GET call to /restapi/v2.1/accounts/#######/envelopes/466077c7-#######/documents/1/tabs:

```
validationPattern            : 
validationMessage            : 
shared                       : false
requireInitialOnSharedChange : false
requireAll                   : false
value                        : 
required                     : true
locked                       : false
concealValueOnDocument       : false
disableAutoSize              : false
maxLength                    : 10
tabLabel                     : PO #
font                         : lucidaconsole
fontColor                    : black
fontSize                     : size9
localePolicy                 : 
documentId                   : 1
recipientId                  : 0287bf0a-2951-4902-b63d-2f438d70a64a
pageNumber                   : 1
xPosition                    : 383
yPosition                    : 61
width                        : 166
height                       : 20
tabId                        : fd51de92-1ccb-4343-81bf-7fd2dbb9ae57
templateRequired             : false
tabType                      : number
```

If I manually type a value into the field in the GUI and exit without sighing it is reflected in the value field in the same call. But when I try to update the field value via API by making a PUT call to /restapi/v2.1/accounts/######/envelopes/466077c7-######/documents/1/tabs with the payload set to:

```
{
            "tabs": {
                "numberTabs": [{
                    "tabLabel": "PO #",
                    "value": "123123123123"
                }]
            }
}
```

It fails with a rather vague error message that I don't understand:

```
{"errorCode":"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR","message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}
```

Looking at the API reference  there is no field named "source" so I don't know how to make this work. I tried referring to the field several different ways in my JSON - by label, guid etc but nothing seems to work. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1):

In the DocuSign eSignature hierarchy of elements, envelopes contain documents and recipients and the tabs have to be associated with both. Therefore, there are two different endpoints that can be used to update the value of tabs, but they do not work the same way. You were trying to use the [Envelopes::UpdateDocumentTabs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs/update) method, whereas you should have used the [Envelope::UpdateTabs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update) method. The former method is used primarily for newer capabilities like [document markup](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-markup) where the document can be modified even while locked (meaning currently opened for signing) while the latter is the correct way for an integration to update the content of the envelope tabs.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign's eSignature API uses `PUT`, not `PATCH`.

So the problem is that when you use the `PUT` method, you are updating **all** of the envelope's tabs for the given document or recipient. And you're setting existing tabs to null if they're not in your PUT call's request object. That's what's causing the error.

So the solution I use is to first [list](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/list) all of an envelope recipient's tabs, then update the data structure as needed, then [update (put)](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update) the updated tab structure.

In this answer, I'm using the EnvelopeRecipientTabs resource. Your example uses the EnvelopeDocumentTabs resource. That should work ok, but note that the response data structure from the `get` is **not** the same as the request data structure for the `put`. So you'll need to munge the data structure as needed.

With the EnvelopeRecipientTabs resource, the response data structure from the `get` is the same as the request data structure for the `put`, so I believe less code is needed. Plus, within the DocuSign object model, tabs belong to recipients. They appear on documents but they belong to recipients.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just tried to do a PUT with all field values but only specifying the value for one field. I get the exact same error message though. Any other ideas as to what I might be missing?

Comment: Because it is an `update` operation, you need to specify values for all of the attributes you received. Use the existing values except for the one you want to change.

Comment: What if the existing tabs are null and I want to keep them null?

Comment: Then set them to value null.

Comment: Ok, I did that and am getting a new error: {"errorCode":"INVALID_TAB_OPERATION","message":"The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. Updated tabs must all be Strikethrough or SmartSection tabs if you're not specifying a valid recipient."}

All of my tabs have a recipient id specified for them. Can you look at my call? https://pastebin.com/JveagaMQ

Comment: Hmmm. A couple of ideas: 1) Use binary search with your update request to figure out where the problem is. 2) Are you making this call before the envelope is sent or afterwards? I will also consult with colleagues to look for other ideas.

Comment: I'd also try it using the EnvelopeRecipientTabs resource methods instead of the EnvelopeDocumentTabs. Also, if you are able to accomplish your goal using the DocuSign web tool, you can use API logging to see what API calls the web tool is using, then mimic that.